# Does translateX() translate from original position or new calculated position, and how to override this behaviour?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I am making a form of a carousel, but the translate function does not seem to be working very well. I translate a block once using `translateX(-100%)` but when applying the same again, it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Link for [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opheliagame/ejuscv34/55/)

Comment: CSS is static. It doesn't get re-computed in steps depending on previous calculation results. So yes, it still translates from the original position. If you want to move it, you will need to change `translate(-100)` to `translate(-200)`.

Comment: But what if I want to apply it in successions, like first `translate(-100)`, and again `translate(-100)`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, there is not. You will have to do the calculation yourself. CSS doesn't care about "successions". The only thing you could do is to nest elements, each with the same translation style, and when you want to apply your change you would create another nested element.